# Object Animator in Android

Tags: android, lua

I want to mimic the animation on 4 Pics 1 Word, wherein the user taps a letter and flies somewhere in the screen. This letter can be a `Button` or an `ImageView`. Please refer to the image below:

[image]

Is this only possible with Corona SDK / Lua? How will I do it in Java? I'm just a beginner so I don't know how to start this so please don't ask any code that I already tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ObjectAnimator` class for performing animations on Android views. For example, if you have to animate the `y` property of the view `mView` you can write:

```
float finalValue = 10f;
ObjectAnimator yAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mView, View.Y, finalValue);
yAnimator.start();
```

For animating more than one property you can write:

```
float finalX = 20f;
float finalY = 30f;
ObjectAnimator xAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mView, View.X, finalX);
ObjectAnimator yAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mView, View.Y, finalY);
new AnimatorSet().playTogether(xAnimator, yAnimator);
```